# Bluebird .finally is not a function ionic error

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, promise, callback

I have a nested callback in an Ionic V1 project.
This is what the nested callback looks like:

```
Locations.getLocations(...)
.then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...)
.then(...).then(...).then(...).finally()
```

When I run it this is the output that gets returned from this callback.

```
Locations.getLocations(...).then(...).then(...)
.then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).finally is not a function
```

If I change `finally` to `then` it works but I need it to use `finally` because I cannot deploy any changes to this app. Also this was working yesterday but not today, don't know why, any thoughts on what’s causing this?

Comment: does `Locations.getLocations` definitely return a *bluebird* promise? Do you know that `.finally(fn)` is sort of equivalent to `.then(fn, fn)`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, they are equivalent. This is an ionic project that was working yesterday, but not today. Also i cannot deploy any changes, so i can't change  `.finally` to `.then()` which would fix this issue.

Comment: `This is an ionic project that was working yesterday, but not today` so, what have you changed in the last 24 hours? That's the source of the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX this project has not been touched for months, but all of a sudden today it doesn't work.

Comment: `has not been touched for months, but all of a sudden today it doesn't work` - thankfully, computers don't actually work like this - there has been a change in the last day or so, the proof is that something worked yesterday, but doesn't today. Skynet has not yet awoken

Comment: @jfriend00 - native promises have a `.finally` - so that's not it

Comment: @JaromandaX - Are you completely sure their platform has `.finally()` on native promises?  Apparently, some `.then()` somewhere is returning something that doesn't have it.  Unless you have another explanation?

Comment: @jfriend00 - `.finally` is [well supported natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#Browser_compatibility) in *modern* platforms (and bluebird too) - so, my point is that *native* promises wouldn't be the issue - but yes, something somewhere is likely returning a promise that is not one of bluebird/native ...as all we see is `...` I'd say it's pretty difficult to debug it for him

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yeah, impossible for us to debug or answer as is.  Insufficient information included.  Voting to close.

Comment: also, considering "it worked yesterday", I doubt something has dropped  `.finally` - my guess is that since "nothing has changed in months", the issue is completely removed from what is presented in the question

Comment: Did you try `.lastly()`? That's a valid alias for earlier versions of ES. Though I agree with other commenters "it worked yesterday" sounds suspicious.

Comment: i tried  .lastly() and it still didn't work. Another question that i had is why would changing .finally to .then  fixes this issue.

Comment: `This is an ionic project that was working yesterday, but not today` | `This project has not been touched for months, but all of a sudden today it doesn't work.`: maybe you removed and added the platform again or run `npm install` and that installed a different (newer) version of `Locations` which works in a different way? What is `Locations`? Could you please add a link to its README file in your question?